# Provide single implementation for multiple interfaces in dependency injection

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection

I am currently writing a WPF application in which I am using dependency injection.

It is divided into multiple projects:

1. WPF application itself
2. Interfaces for services
3. Implementation for said services
4. other stuff that is unrelated to this question

Now I have an interface that is generic and the generic type is passed in from the WPF application. It is also defined within the WPF application and not defined in another library that can be accessed by other project, so I can't access the type anywhere else besides the WPF app.

I want to be able to access the service for the generic interface in a non-generic way, but how would I do that?

Imagine the following situation:

I have my interfaces defined like this. One is the non-generic base version and the generic one merely exposes an object of the generic type.

```
public interface IService
{
    void DoStuff();
}

public interface IService<T> : IService
{
    T GenericData { get; }
}
```

I implement said interfaces like this:

```
public class ServiceImplementation<T> : IService<T>
{
    public T GenericData { get; }

    public void DoStuff() { } // Some irrelevant implementation
}
```

When I inject an object of the type into another service defined in the WPF app, I can obviously access the generic implementation, because I know the generic type. However when I want to access the service in another library where I don't know the generic type, I want to access the non-generic version of the service.

How do I make sure that the same object is provided for both interfaces when added to the ServiceCollection as a Singleton?

```
class WpfOnlyObject
{
    // Irrelevant stuff
}

// In the App.xaml.cs
public void ConfigureServices(ServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IService<WpfOnlyObject>, ServiceImplementation<WpfOnlyObject>>();
    services.AddSingleton<IService, ServiceImplementation<WpfOnlyObject>>();
}
```

If this question was answered already, I am really sorry, but I couldn't find a suitable answer here on SO.

Comment: `IServiceCollection` is a bit weak in this respect -- you don't tend to see it outside of ASP.NET much. I think you might have to register `IService` as a delegate which fetches `IService<WpfOnlyObject>` from the container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what [canton7](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1086121/canton7) suggested, I did the following and it worked flawlessly.

```
// taken from the code in the question
public void ConfigureServices(ServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IService<WpfOnlyObject>, ServiceImplementation<WpfOnlyObject>>();
    services.AddSingleton<IService>(serviceProvider => serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IService<WpfOnlyObject>>());
}
```